# Why my website (on strato) can't show the Background image I want to set with javascript? *(locally it works great)*

Tags: javascript, image, background-image

I would like to **finish** my **card game** and bring it **online** so I can share it :)

However, it fails because the pictures of the cards are not shown on my website. (it worked great on my local server)

The card to show is set by javascript as a .style.backgroundImage property, as the source code shows when inspecting.

However, it does not display the picture of the card.

Code example

HTML part:

```
<div class="first layer">

        <div class="cards" id="two_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="three_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="four_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="five_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="six_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="seven_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="eight_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="nine_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="ten_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="eleven_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="twelve_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="thirteen_1"></div>
        <div class="cards" id="fourteen_1"></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript part:

```
            let number;
            if (card_nr == 2) number = "two";
            if (card_nr == 3) number = "three";
            if (card_nr == 4) number = "four";
            if (card_nr == 5) number = "five";
            if (card_nr == 6) number = "six";
            if (card_nr == 7) number = "seven";
            if (card_nr == 8) number = "eight";
            if (card_nr == 9) number = "nine";
            if (card_nr == 10) number = "ten";
            if (card_nr == 11) number = "eleven";
            if (card_nr == 12) number = "twelve";
            if (card_nr == 13) number = "thirteen";
            if (card_nr == 14) number = "fourteen";


            if (document.getElementById(number + "_1").style.backgroundImage === "") {
                document.getElementById(number + "_1").style.background = "url(img/" + cardToShow +".svg)";
                document.getElementById(number + "_1").style.backgroundSize = "100%";
                document.getElementById(number + "_1").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"; 
            }
```

Comment: It'd be great if you share your real website to verify the issue. Did you upload the Pictures to your host? Also check the console (F12 on chrome) for errors.

Comment: Open chrome developer tools. Go to networks tab. See if there is any error.

Comment: I think I found the issue! :) .. character in string is lowercase but the pictures are uppercase example: 2h.png -> 2H.png work I'll try it now thanks for answers

Comment: yeah greate .. works! ... but why my localserver ignore this?